# The option 'android.enableD8' is deprecated

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using AGP 7.0+ now.
Today, i found this warning because i set `android.enableD8=true` in `gradle.properties` file.

> The option 'android.enableD8' is deprecated.
> The current default is 'true'.
> It was removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> For more details, see https://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/d8-overview.html.
> Affected Modules: myproject

it definitely means we don't need to use `android.enableD8=true` anymore.
But what i want to know is that the AGP supports it automatically like opt-in?
where can i see about a referecne?